# typescript null errors inside of *ngif template

Tags: angular, typescript

I am defining what I thought was a very simple function that draws a value returned from the server if the value exists.  It failed to compile with a typescript error saying "value is possibly null".

Since this is inside the *ngif, I feel that should be enough to say it is not null.  But just to be safe, I added the not-null directive (!) to the object.  But I still get the error.  I even added it to the properties of the object just in case that made a difference.  Still am getting the error.

```
<div *ngIf="info">
  <p>Info Id: {{info!.id!}}</p>
  <p>Info databaseText: {{info!.databaseText!}}</p>
  <p>Info localText: {{info!.localText!}}</p>
  <p>Info computedText: {{info!.computedText!}}</p>
</div>
```

Not sure what to try next.  Any ideas would be appreciated.  I do not want to disable the typescript null check.

Comment: use ? instead, but the heart of the issue is that you're not typing it correctly in your component.... IMO, strict null checks in typescript are really problematic / cause more problems than they solve

Comment: Are you sure that the error is caused by that section of the template? Did you try without the `!` at the end (e.g. `{{info!.localText}}`)? That is the usage given in the  [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-non-null-assertion-operator---).

Comment: @bryan60 that is interesting - what is the correct way to declare a variable that could be null or could be an arbitrary object from the server?

Comment: Id need to see how you did it but you need to write an interface for it and type it. It’s much easier without strict null checks though.

Comment: @bryan60 this solved the problem.  The variable was incorrectly declared in another file.  Changing the type to `any` solved it.  Do you want to submit that as an answer and I can accept it as such?

Comment: None of the ansers really answer how to supress errors inside an *ngIf, that brougth me here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @bryan60 suggested, the issue turned out to be an incorrect declaration.  I changed the info variable to be `info: any;` and it now works without any ! or ? required.  Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem as usually you're using TypeScript for, well, the types.

Answer (score 0):

It should be the question mark. Therefore

```
<div *ngIf="info">
  <p>Info Id: {{info?.id}}</p>
  etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you're having **`!`** in front of the properties, try without it and it should work,

```
<div *ngIf="info">
  <p>Info Id: {{info.id}}</p>
  <p>Info databaseText: {{info.databaseText!}}</p>
  <p>Info localText: {{info.localText!}}</p>
  <p>Info computedText: {{info.computedText!}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please elaborate why.

Answer (score 0):

use optional parameter like

```
  <div *ngIf="info">
    <p>Info Id: {{info?.id!}}</p>
    <p>Info localText: {{info.?localText!}}</p>
  </div>
```

if thats what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
  <p>Info Id: {{info!.id!}}</p>
  <p>Info databaseText: {{info!.databaseText!}}</p>
  <p>Info localText: {{info!.localText!}}</p>
  <p>Info computedText: {{info!.computedText!}}</p>
</div>
```

so what does this mean?
`<p>Info Id: {{info!.id!}}</p>`

The `!` is called a Non-null assertion operator. 
In simple terms we are saying telling typescript no matter what happens the value before `!` cannot be null or defined. 
In your example above, it is possible that info is defined, but info.computedText or any other property of info is not defined or is null.

Only use the Non-Null assertion operator in cases when typescript can always be 100% sure that the value you are checking cannot be null or undefined.

If you Google search Non-null assertion operator you will find lots more on this topic. 
:)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `<div *ngIf="info">` should be enough: inside it you can simply use `{{info.id}}`, etc. without further null checks, so the *real* problem is that the compiler is not recognizing the `ngIf`.

Possible *reason* is that you are *missing* this component in the `declarations` of the `@NgModule` in your app.module.ts.